# How to create multiple falling down objects by using threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

**   Here i created only one moving object ,i want to create more objects which falls down and has random X coordinate .i know i should implement runnable and i should create squres then store them in a collection but its really hard for me to merge everything.i also might have done some mistakes btw . Could you help me some ?  **

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project3 extends JFrame {
    public Project3(){
        super("Game");
        setSize(600,600);
        add(new Game(600,600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Project3());
    }

    class Squares{
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Squares(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        private int score;
        private java.util.List<Squares> shapeList=new ArrayList<>();
        private boolean play ;
        private int X=50;
        private int Y=0;
        Timer timer=new Timer(10,this);

        public Game(int w , int h){
            Dimension d = new Dimension(w, h);
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.fillRect(X,Y,60,60);
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Y=Y+5;
            repaint();
            if(Y==600){
                Random random=new Random();
                Y=0;
                X=random.nextInt(600-60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Project3 extends JFrame {
    public Project3() {
        super("Game");
        setSize(600, 600);
        add(new Game(600,600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Project3());
    }

    class Square {
        public int squareX;
        public int squareY;
        int squareW = 25;
        int squareH = 25;

        public Square(int X, int Y) {
            this.squareX = X;
            this.squareY = Y;
        }

        public int getSquareX() {
            return squareX;
        }

        public void setSquareX(int X) {
            this.squareX = X;
        }

        public int getSquareY() {
            return squareY;
        }

        public void setSquareY(int Y) {
            this.squareY = Y;
        }

    }


    class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener ,Runnable,MouseListener {
        public int score;
        private java.util.List<Square> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, this);
        private boolean play= true;

        public Game(int w, int h) {
            Dimension d = new Dimension(600, 600);
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            add(new Label("SCORE...."),BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            for (Square s:shapeList) {
                g.fillRect(s.squareX,s.squareY,25,25);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (Square k : shapeList) {
                k.setSquareY(k.getSquareY() + 5);
                repaint();
            }
        }
        public void stop() {
            play = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(play){

                int randomNumber=(int)(Math.random()*600)+1;
                shapeList.add(new Square(randomNumber,0));

                for (Square k : shapeList) {
                    if (k.getSquareY()== 600) {
                    stop();
                }try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int mouseX=e.getX();
            int mouseY=e.getY();
            for (Square s:shapeList){
                if ((mouseX > s.squareX) && (mouseX < s.squareX + s.squareW) && (mouseY > s.squareY) && (mouseY < s.squareY + s.squareH)) {
                    shapeList.remove(s);
                    score++;
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "i know i should implement runnable" - I don't really see a connection between Runnable and your usecase. Just store all squares in a collection and iterate over them in your main loop or something. No need for multithreading here.

Comment: You have to know that a CPU can do billions of instructions per second. Calculating the simple movement *dx* for one element, which is just some simple arithmetics, can be done in some instructions. I don't think it's worth it to do multithreading here at all ..

Comment: On top of what akuzminykh said, multithreading so simple operation might actually be harmful to performance - creating new Threads is quite expensive and then you have to coordinate them (+ content switching) which isn't free as well

Comment: i see , actually i have know that something was wrong but im quite new in java could you tell some details , for example how should i collect them in to a collection or where exactly collect them ,i mean in which method .

Comment: should i create and collect them in the constructor of Game ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces three layers of 'snow flakes' which drift towards the bottom of the screen.

Have a look over it, for tips:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.Random;

public class AnimatedSnowFall {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    AnimatedSnowFall() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ui.add(new SnowFall());
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            AnimatedSnowFall o = new AnimatedSnowFall();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setResizable(false);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class SnowFall extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Dimension prefSize = new Dimension(1600, 900);
    SnowFlake[] farFlakes = new SnowFlake[200];
    SnowFlake[] midFlakes = new SnowFlake[150];
    SnowFlake[] closeFlakes = new SnowFlake[75];
    Color farColor = new Color(100,100,255);
    Color midColor = new Color(150,150,255);
    Color closeColor = new Color(255,255,255);

    SnowFall() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < farFlakes.length; ii++) {
            farFlakes[ii] = new SnowFlake(prefSize.width, prefSize.height, 2, 4);
        }
        for (int ii = 0; ii < midFlakes.length; ii++) {
            midFlakes[ii] = new SnowFlake(prefSize.width, prefSize.height, 3, 6);
        }
        for (int ii = 0; ii < closeFlakes.length; ii++) {
            closeFlakes[ii] = new SnowFlake(prefSize.width, prefSize.height, 4, 8);
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer(50, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(farColor);
        for (SnowFlake snowFlake : farFlakes) {
            snowFlake.draw(g);
        }

        g.setColor(midColor);
        for (SnowFlake snowFlake : midFlakes) {
            snowFlake.draw(g);
        }

        g.setColor(closeColor);
        for (SnowFlake snowFlake : closeFlakes) {
            snowFlake.draw(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return prefSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
}

class SnowFlake {

    int w;
    int h;
    int x;
    int y;
    int size;
    int speed;
    static Random r = new Random();

    SnowFlake(int w, int h, int size, int speed) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        x = r.nextInt(w);
        y = r.nextInt(h);
        this.size = size;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        y += speed;
        if (y > h) {
            x = r.nextInt(w);
            y = 0;
        }
        g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Incrementing the `y` value during every paint operation is fragile. E.g. when you drag the window partially outside the screen and back, the additional system generated paint requests cause strange artifacts. You can eliminate this by calling `f.setIgnoreRepaint(true);` before opening the window, however, the code still is subject to paint coercing. This might not happen with such a trivial program, but it’s generally better to calculate the position based on truly elapsed time (`System.nanoTime()`, calculate difference to the value at start time). It’s not so much more complicated.

Comment: You might want to call the OP's attention to the the fact that you are using a `Timer` to drive the animation. The fact that OP wanted to use a thread-per-moving-object is a sign that OP is thinking procedurally, rather than event-driven-lly.

Comment: @Holger *"It’s not so much more complicated."* I'll believe that when I see the MRE. ;)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yeah .. I could've done that, but it was way more fun to write the code than read the question enough to actually understand it. *"The fact that OP wanted to use a thread-per-moving-object is a sign that OP is thinking procedurally, rather than event-driven-lly."* Huh..

Comment: E.g. insert the field declaration `long t0 = System.nanoTime();` into `SnowFlake` and change the `draw` method to `public void draw(Graphics g) { int currY = (int)(y + (System.nanoTime() - t0) * speed / 50_000_000); if(currY > h) { x = r.nextInt(w); currY = y = currY%h; t0 = System.nanoTime(); } g.fillOval(x, currY, size, size); }`. Perhaps, it can be simplified, I didn’t spend too much time on it.

Comment: OK, Here's what I wanted to say: Your code is object oriented: Your "snowflakes" are _objects_ that react to events when their methods are called. That's typical of good GUI code, but newbies don't "get" OO right away. The OP's code has some OO elements, but that may be mostly forced by the Swing framework. The fact that they want to use threads (i.e., _procedures_) to animate their mobs reveals their _procedural_ mind set. I suggested that you call more attention to how you use the `Timer` because that might help them to really understand how to design an OO GUI application.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You make good points. I think your understanding of the basic problem here, outstrips mine. (I'm not much of a 'designer' as such.) Would you consider working that idea up into an answer? I really think you can explain it better than I can. At this moment, there is no allowance to add a bounty, but I'd be happy to add one when it becomes possible.